# How to optimize directory listing from list of paths?

Tags: c++, string, performance, optimization, fuse

While writing a fuse filesystem, I have an `unordered_map<std::string, struct stat>` as a cache, that is primed with *all* files and directories at startup in order to reduce reads on hard drives.

To satisfy `readdir()` callbacks I wrote the following loop:

```
const int sp = path == "/" ? 0 : path.size();
for (auto it = stat_cache.cbegin(); it != stat_cache.cend(); it++)
{
    if (it->first.size() > sp)
    {
        int ls = it->first.find_last_of('/');
        if (it->first.find(path, 0) == 0 && ls == sp)
            filler(buf, it->first.substr(ls + 1).c_str(), const_cast<struct stat*>(&it->second), 0, FUSE_FILL_DIR_PLUS);
    }
}
```

The idea being that an object which's path is beginning with the directory path and having its last slash at the end of the directory path would be a member of it. I've tested this thoroughly and it works.
Illustration:

```
Reading directory: /foo/bar
Candidate file:    /bazboo/oof - not in dir (wrong prefix)
Candidate file:    /foo/bar/baz/boo - not in dir (wrong lastslash location)
Candidate file:    /foo/bar/baz - in dir!
```

Now, however, this is surprisingly slow (especially in a filesystem with over half a million objects in the cache). Valgrind/Callgrind especially blames the `std::string:find_last_of()` and `std::string::find()` calls.

I already added the `if (it->first.size() > sp)` in an attempt to speed up the loop, but the performance gain was minimal at best.

I also tried speeding this routine up by parallelizing the loop in four chunks, but that ended in a segfault during `unordered_map::cbegin()`.
I don't have the actual code anymore, but I believe it looked something like this:

```
const int sp = path == "/" ? 0 : path.size();
ThreadPool<4> tpool;
ulong cq = stat_cache.size()/4;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    tpool.addTask([&] () {
        auto it = stat_cache.cbegin();
        std::next(it, i * cq);
        for (int j = 0; j < cq && it != stat_cache.cend(); j++, it++)
        {
            if (it->first.size() > sp)
            {
                int ls = it->first.find_last_of('/');
                if (it->first.find(path, 0) == 0 && ls == sp)
                    filler(buf, it->first.substr(ls + 1).c_str(), const_cast<struct stat*>(&it->second), 0, FUSE_FILL_DIR_PLUS);
            }
        }
    });
}
tpool.joinAll();
```

I also tried this with splitting it by map buckets, which `unordered_map::cbegin(int)` provides a convenient overload for, but it still segfaulted out.

Again, I'm currently working with the first (non-parallel) code and would like help for that one since the parallelized one didn't work. I just thought I'd include my parallelized attempt for completeness, noob-bashing and proof of effort.

Are there any other options for optimizing this loop?

Comment: If the code is otherwise working, and you are just asking to optimize it for speed/efficiency, then you should post this on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Use not `unordered_map` but `map`, call `upper_bound` passing in the directory name to find the first entry in O(lg N), then all the other entries are adjacent.  Final cost of `readdir`: O(k + lg N)

Answer (score 2):

The trivial thing to do here is to change the `if` from this:

```
if (it->first.find(path, 0) == 0 && ls == sp)
```

to simply:

```
if (ls == sp && it->first.find(path, 0) == 0)
```

Obviously, comparing two integers is much faster than looking for a substring.

 I wouldn't guarantee it'll turn the performance around, but it's a trivial thing that may help to skip a lot of unnecessary `std::string::find` calls. Maybe the compiler already does that, I'd look into the disassembly.

Also, since filepathes are anyway unique, I would use `std::vector<std::pair<...>>` instead - better cache locality, less memory allocations etc. just remember to reserve the size first.

Comment: another trivial modification is `it->first.find_last_of('/',sp);`

Comment: I'm not sure if a `std::vector<std::pair<...>>` would be a good choice, since the cache will get a lot of random accesses based on the string key, for example for `getattr()` calls. With a vector I'd have to scan the entire thing until I found it which is no longer O(1) which unordered_map promises. Right?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast you can add all the paths and sort them, then look for the specific key with a binary search. as always, one cannot guarantee performance gain, until you benchmark these two suggestions, these are all theories.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes That seems to break it. Maybe because it searches between [0;pos] and not [pos;npos], if I'm interpreting the manual right.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast, ops I confused it with find_first_of; anyway, you can still jump sp ahead to start the search of the last '/' ( using either <algorithm>, or something like boost::string_ref )

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is

```
for (auto it = stat_cache.cbegin(); it != stat_cache.cend(); it++)
```

effectively removing unordered_maps greatest advantage and exposing one of the weaknesses. Not only do you not have its O(1) lookup but you might have to search through the map to find an entry, this makes the rutine O(N) with a very large K (if not an extra N ie. O(N^2)).

Fastest solution would be O(1) for the lookup (in a lucky unordered map), O(strlen(target)) in a bucket scheme or O(lgN) in a binary. Then along the `struct stat` have list of children, for O(#children).